# Trying to create a script that will stop a DoS-attack

Tags: python, denial-of-service

We are trying to create a script using Python to block a DoS-script we created as part of a school project. But we are having a hard time finding any information about how we could do this. We have tried to get iptables to work using Python but it will not work or get installed in either 2.7, 3.4 or 3.6 versions.

Are there some bright minds out there who could give us some tips on how to create a script that would counter or block a port/IP or even the MAC-address to a script?

This is the current script we are trying to work on/around, that we are hoping will block a DoS-attack when we get it up and working:

**We are NOT taking any credit for this script, it is only shown as an example on what we are trying out in hopes that it will give us a better understanding on how it should work.**

```
import sys 
import scapy.all as scapy
import iptc
import time


# Required Data Field
Field = {
# Key      Value  Required
'count'      : (5,    False) ,
'iface'      : (None, True),  
'timeout'    : (None, False),
}


# Main Class For Finding DoS Packets
class DoSDetector:
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    All Arguments And Keywords Will Directly Passed To
    Python Scapy Sniff Function.

    """
    self.args = args
    self.kwargs = kwargs
    self.data={}
    self.Sniffing_Start()

   def extract_packets(self, pkt):
    """
    Function For Extracting Packets.
     This Function Is Specially Created For Filtering 
     DoS Packets.
    """
    if pkt.haslayer(scapy.Dot11Deauth):
     victim1 = pkt.addr2
     victim2 = pkt.addr1
     if str([victim1, victim2]) in self.data.keys():
      self.data[str([victim1, victim2])]=self.data[str([victim1, victim2])]+1
     else:
      self.data[str([victim1, victim2])]=1
     self.print_values()
    return

   def print_values(self):
    """
    Function For Printing Values
    """
    line = 0
    for a,b in self.data.iteritems():
     v1, v2 = eval(a)
     print "\t[#] DoS Packet : {} <---> {} | Packets : {}".format(v1,v2,b)
     line+=1

    # Backspace Trick
    sys.stdout.write("\033[{}A".format(line))
    return

   def Sniffing_Start(self):
    '''
    Function For Creating Python Scapy.sniff Function
    '''
    scapy.sniff(prn=self.extract_packets, *self.args, **self.kwargs)
    return


# Drop packets from an attacker
class DropIt:
    def drop_packet:
    if xx
      rule = iptc.Rule()
      match = iptc.Match(rule, "tcp")
      target = iptc.Target(rule, "DROP")
      rule.add_match(match)
      rule.target = target
    else
        pass
    return



# Main Function
def main(*args, **kwargs):
 DoSDetector(*args, **kwargs)
 return


# Main Trigger
if __name__=='__main__':
 if len(sys.argv)==2:
  main(iface=sys.argv[1])
 else:
  print (" [ Error ] Please Provide Monitor Mode Interface Name ALso \n\n\t:~# sudo {} mon0 ".format(sys.argv[0]))
```

This would help us tremendously in getting further on our project.

Would like to point out that this is not our script from scratch, but we are looking for something like it.

"The thing that we could have made more clear is that the script linked in our question is more of an example. We wanted to find one that works, and by then understanding how it works write our own". -edit

Thanks in advance!

Regards

Comment: I guess that Stackoverflow does not allow people to get tips on how to solve a solution. Looks like we won't be getting any help from here then.